# Referring to an image file uploaded as `Image` type field without /sites/

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I am using a content type with `Image` type fields to hold images uploaded to a web site. I want to display these images both on distinct pages (easy) and inline on other pages (almost *even* easier).

However, I don't want to expose `/sites/default/files/` in the image URL, and I certainly don't want to include it in the image tag's `src` attribute when I refer to the image from some other page.

How do I include at an arbitrary location on an arbitrary page an image uploaded like that, without exposing the physical directory structure in the link? I tried using the `URL aliases` feature provided by the Path module, but it wouldn't let me point to anything in /sites as such.

Comment: What problem is having `/sites/default/files/` in the image URL causing you? Knowing that might help to understand the problem a bit better

Comment: @Clive It isn't an actual *problem* right *now* because this particular Drupal installation only hosts one site, but if I want to consolidate multiple sites within a single Drupal installation, I can easily see it becoming a problem (file name collisions, differentiating between files from different sites, ...).

Comment: In a multisite files will be underneath the respective site's folder though (`sites/site1.com/files`, `sites/sites2.com/files`) so there's no chance of a collision there

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symlink in the drupal root using:

```
ln -s sites/default/files images
```

and then set the src attribute to something like:

```
/images/myimage.jpg
```

Really not sure what you would gain by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess and mod_rewrite. Like [described on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524289/how-do-i-mod-rewrite-my-url-to-hide-the-subfolder#4524389). In my opinion it's the cleanest solution, but other ones may still be valid.

Then, in your template.php you need to rewrite rendered image addresses to reflect new ones.